# CDR usage in lisp

Tags: lisp

is it not possible to take a `cdr` of a `cdr`?
i have this code and the last two statements returns a nil

```
CL-USER 31 : 1 > (CHOICES 'PANTRY)
((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))

CL-USER 32 : 1 > (car(CHOICES 'PANTRY))
(NORTH KITCHEN)

CL-USER 33 : 1 > (car(car(CHOICES 'PANTRY)))
NORTH

CL-USER 34 : 1 > (cdr(CHOICES 'PANTRY))
((WEST DINING-ROOM))

CL-USER 35 : 1 > (car(cdr(cdr(CHOICES 'PANTRY))))
NIL

CL-USER 36 : 1 > (cdr(cdr(CHOICES 'PANTRY)))
NIL
```

In the last two statements I'm aiming for a `(DINING-ROOM)` result, they're two different ways i tried to get that.

Answer (score 3):

You should think of [`car`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm) as [`first`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_firstc.htm) and [`cdr`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm) as [`rest`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rest.htm).

Then it would be clear that `(second x)` is the same as `(first (rest x))` which is the same as `(car (cdr x))`, i.e., `(cadr x)`.

This way it would probably be easy to see that, since

```
(second (second '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))))
==> DINING-ROOM
```

and since [`second`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_firstc.htm) is the same as [`cadr`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm), then

```
(cadr (cadr '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))))
==> DINING-ROOM
```

or, to make the long story short:

```
(cadadr '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM)))
==> DINING-ROOM
```

If you want the *list* `(DINING-ROOM)` instead, just drop the last `a`:

```
(cdadr '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM)))
==> (DINING-ROOM)
```

Note that you are dropping the `a` which is the *last* in the order of application, so it comes *first* in the function name.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of two elements.

```
CL-USER 1 > '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))
((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))

CL-USER 2 > (length '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM)))
2
```

You remove the first one and keep the rest. Now it has length *one*.

```
CL-USER 3 > (cdr '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM)))
((WEST DINING-ROOM))

CL-USER 4 > (length '((WEST DINING-ROOM)))
1

CL-USER 5 > (cdr '((WEST DINING-ROOM)))
NIL
```

You remove the first one and keep the rest. Now it has length *zero*.

```
CL-USER 6 > (length 'nil)
0
```

Then:

```
CL-USER 7 > '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))
((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM))
```

You remove the first element and keep the rest.

```
CL-USER 8 > (cdr '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM)))
((WEST DINING-ROOM))
```

You take the first element.

```
CL-USER 9 > (car '((WEST DINING-ROOM)))
(WEST DINING-ROOM)
```

You remove the first element and keep the rest.

```
CL-USER 10 > (cdr '(WEST DINING-ROOM))
(DINING-ROOM)
```

cDr ... cAr ... cDr: together we have `cDADr`:

```
CL-USER 11 > (cdadr '((NORTH KITCHEN) (WEST DINING-ROOM)))
(DINING-ROOM)
```